# How to register a System Supplied Property Handler for XPS and OPC files in registry for a custom file type?

Tags: windows-shell, xps

I'm creating a custom file format for use by my application based on the OPC (or maybe the XPS) file format.  This MSDN link, [Using System-Supplied Property Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#systemsupplied_prophandlers),  gives an example but it doesn't appear to be correct.  Does anybody know how to do this properly?

Edit:
This can apply to OPC files as well as XPS.  XPS is build on top of OPC.

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct?

Comment: The example is for the OLE DocFile handler.  The GUID of this handler (given in the table) is not used anywhere in the example.

Comment: Looks like a typo, the GUID shown ({9DBD2C50-62AD-11d0-B806-00C04FD706EC}) is for `.doc` not `.OLEDocFile` (I don't even have that file extension in my registry).

Comment: Thanks.  It appears the entire example is messed up.  Did a search for {BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1} and it appears to be for thumbnail preview handlers.  I'm just starting to learn shell and related registry and they sure do not make it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1. Create a key named with your extension (e.g. a key named .doc) under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers.
2. Then set the default value for the key you just created to {45670FA8-ED97-4F44-BC93-305082590BFB}
3. Under Root/SystemFileAssociations add a key named with your file extension (e.g. .doc).
4. Under that key add "shellex\PropertyHandler"
5. Set default value under the PropertyHandler key to {45670FA8-ED97-4F44-BC93-305082590BFB}.

   6. Now you have to tell Windows what properties to display depending on circumstance.

      - Add FullDetails, PreviewDetails, ExtendedTileInfo, and InfoTip keys to the Root/SystemFileAssociations/ key.

This property handler is good for both OPC (open package conventions) and XPS files.

- PreviewDetails is the property pane at the bottom of windows explorer (Win 7) or the left hand side of explorer (Win 8).
- FullDetails is the properties you see when you right click and select properties and go to the Details tab.

  - InfoTip is the properties you see when you hover over a file.
  - ExtendedTileInfo I'm not sure about.  I think it's the properties you see when you select the content folder view in explorer.

{45670FA8-ED97-4F44-BC93-305082590BFB} is the GUID for the OPC/XPS property handler given in the MSDN link in my question.

OPC is basically a standard for creating a (zipped) file type.  Can see more here: [MSDN Magazine - Aug. 2007 OPC - A New Standard For Packaging Your Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163372.aspx).

I only tested in Windows 7 but it should work in Vista and above.  I'll post back after I do further testing.